# Java robot does not stop

Tags: java, jnativehook

I have a problem with the operation of the JNativeHook library and Java Robot. My robot should run when I press F9 and it should stop when I click F6, but it is not working. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Every time I tried to stop the robot it just does not stop. The code says that when I press F6 the work value should change to false and the while loop should stop calling the robot.

```
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main extends JFrame implements NativeKeyListener {

    static int szerokosc = 2;
    static int dlugosc = 10;
    static boolean work = false;
    static Robot robot;
    static JTextField t1;
    static JTextField t3;
    static JTextField p1;
    JFrame jf;
    JLabel label, label2, label4;

    public Main() {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
            jf = new JFrame();
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("pickaxe.png");
            JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
            jf.setLocation(800, 300);
            tp.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 32));
            jf.setTitle("Kopacz by Macijke");
            jf.setIconImage(img.getImage());
            jf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 350));
            jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            label = new JLabel("Kliknij F9, aby włączyć kopanie na 6/3/3!");
            label.setBounds(50, 10, 250, 20);
            jf.add(label);

            label2 = new JLabel("Komenda nr 1");
            label2.setBounds(10, 20, 250, 90);
            t1 = new JTextField("/repair");
            t1.setBounds(100, 50, 150, 30);
            label2.setVisible(true);

            label4 = new JLabel("Długość");
            label4.setBounds(10, 240, 250, 90);
            t3 = new JTextField("10");
            t3.setBounds(65, 270, 50, 30);

            // ============
            p1 = new JTextField("11");
            p1.setBounds(255, 50, 30, 30);

            // ============

            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
            jf.setLayout(null);
            jf.add(t1);
            jf.add(t3);
            jf.add(label2);
            jf.add(label4);
            jf.add(p1);
            jf.pack();
            jf.setVisible(true);
        } catch (AWTException var3) {
            var3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        } catch (NativeHookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new Main());
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_F6) {
            work = false;
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_F9) {
            dlugosc = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());
            work = true;
            int i = 1;
            while (work) {
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                for (int z = 0; z < dlugosc; z++) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                    robot.delay(210);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);

                }

                for (int a = 0; a < szerokosc; a++) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                    robot.delay(150);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                }

                for (int z = 0; z < dlugosc; z++) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    robot.delay(210);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);

                }

                for (int z = 0; z < szerokosc; z++) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                    robot.delay(150);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                }
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

                if (i % 25 == 0) {
                    robot.delay(100);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                    robot.delay(250);
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
                    robot.delay(4000);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
                    robot.delay(250);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    robot.delay(100);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `work` as `volatile`:

`static volatile boolean work = false;`

### The problem is probrably due to synchronization

When your method `nativeKeyReleased` is invoked, it is going to run on a different thread, and all variables visible to a thread are instead copies.

Your code does not work because when you set `work` as `true`, this change will not propagate to the copy your `while` loop is looking at.

The `volatile` keyword will ensure that this variable is written to the main memory as well, instead of the CPU cache. thus achieving synchronization among different threads.

This [article](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/volatile.html) describes well how volatile works in Java.

### Side Note

If you need to set the value of `work` in different locations, you should use `synchronized` setter method instead of a `volatile` field, as stated [here](https://jorosjavajams.wordpress.com/volatile-vs-synchronized/#:%7E:text=When%20to%20use%20Volatile%20over,written%20to%20by%20multiple%20threads.)

The rule of thumb is:

> Use Volatile when you variables are going to get read by **multiple**
> threads, but written to by **only one** thread
>
> Use Synchronized when your variables will get read and written to by
> **multiple** threads

Comment: That volatile flushes to main memory is common misconception. Modern CPUs have coherent caches due to cache coherence protocols like MESI. Forcing to read and write to main memory would make concurrent programs extremely slow.

Comment: The article posted suffers from the 'flushing to main' memory fallacy as well.